# I think I am on to something - Conditional links to serve HTML or Flash

Tags: html5-video

My home page does not have any videos, but other pages have video.  What do you think of this code.

```
<script>
     var ie=false;
     <!--[if ie]>ie=true</p>-->
</script>

<body>
<script>

if (ie){
     document.write("<a href='My Flash Page'>IE7,8,9 not IE10<a>")
} else {
     document.write("<a href='My HTML5 Page'>all browsers + IE10, but not IE7,8,9<a>")
}

</script>
</body>
```

My home page does not have video, but the link will serve my other page in HTML5 or flash.
If broswer is IE7,8,9 then link goes to a web page with a flash player.(IE10 ignores code).
All other browers to include IE10 go to a web page with raw HTML5 video (full screen support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a better way to have the script inside of the conditional IE comment than having the condition inside of the script.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var ie=false;
     </script>
     <!--[IF IE]>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               ie=true;
            </script>
        <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks Suvi, makes sense.  Just one small typo, should be "ie=true;".

Comment: Thank you Chris Hood. I changed it.